# Angular2 & Typescript: Error TS2339: Property 'selectpicker' does not exist on type 'ElementFinder'

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, compiler-errors, bootstrap-selectpicker

Unfortunately we have to use old libraries in the current project, that require jQuery. The activation of those happen in the lifecycle hook section "ngAfterViewChecked". Due to fact, that TypeScript cannot resolve it at the right time, it outputs the error:

> Error TS2339: 
>   Property 'selectpicker' does not exist 
>   on type 'ElementFinder'.

That is the concerned code block:

```
 ngAfterViewChecked () {
    if (this.agency) {
      //noinspection TypeScriptUnresolvedFunction
      $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    }
  }
```

I've added the line `//noinspection TypeScriptUnresolvedFunction` before the selectpicker activation, but it did not help.

We have a preconfigured build-system and because of such of errors it "bounces" us. How can I get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extend the type definitions of jQuery. Which means merging the jQuery namespace with your custom `.d.ts` that defined the `.selectpicker()` method. See the documentation for help:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html

Depending on your jQuery definition files this might work:

```
interface JQuery {
  selectpicker: () => void;
}
```

Comment: I've already a workaround with `declare var $:any;`, it also works, but I wonder, why I cannot tell TypeScript ignore such of errors.  Why does `//noinspection` not work? Second question: Is there an existing `.d.ts` file, which I could use? Selectpicker is only a single example, there is amount of functions, that have to be declared. Thank you very much,..

Comment: If you're using TS <2.0 you can try to find it here: http://definitelytyped.org/ I don't not what `// noinspection` mean. If you chose TypeScript you want static types and errors, otherwise just JavaScript ;)